# How to check the correctness of an Ajax returned JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I use ajax to run MySQL query and `echo` `json_encode` result, so that I can get a JSON object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: phpUrl,
    data: command,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function(jsonData) {
        //XXX
    }
```

The JSON object should be like: `{cols: [XXXX], rows: [XXXX]}`.

Sometimes there is error msg from MySQL query, so the returned JSON object is not valid. How can I determine if the returned JSON object is valid or not?

**edit**

In http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, it says "the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown". How to handle the parse error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: phpUrl,
    data: command,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function(jsonData) {
        //XXX
    },
    error:function(xhr,err){
        if (err=='parsererror') alert('invalid json');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If MySQL throws an error, just return some sort of JSON that explains it, like:

```
// do mysql query
if (mysql_errno()) {
  echo json_encode(array(
    'error' => true,
    'errorno' => mysql_errno(),
    'message' => mysql_error()
  ));
} else {
  //echo original json
}
```

Then your ajax function just looks for the 'error' key, and if it exists and is try you have an error to report.